# The Scrollbar and import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar; is error also PDF viewer is crashing

Tags: java, android, pdf, firebase-realtime-database, scrollbar

The `ScrollBar` and `import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar;` is not working

Also, when I run on a device then I tap the pdf I want to view the app is crashing.

[image: This is Screenshot where the errors i cant solve]

[image: This activity list the pdf file in the listview from phone Directory Storage]

please anyone could help me?

I im very new in Programming 
I can't sleep with errors

HERE ARE THE CODES :

```
    import com.example.mcphil.avastus.R;
    import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar;
    import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
    import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
    import java.io.File;

public class PDF_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_);


        //PDFVIEW SHALL DISPLAY OUR PDFS
        PDFView pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        //SCROLLBAR TO ENABLE SCROLLING
       ScrollBar scrollBar1 = (ScrollBar) findViewById(R.id.scrollBar);
       pdfView.setScrollBar(scrollBar1);
        //VERTICAL SCROLLING
        scrollBar1.setHorizontal(false);
        //SACRIFICE MEMORY FOR QUALITY
        pdfView.useBestQuality(true)

        //UNPACK OUR DATA FROM INTENT
        Intent i=this.getIntent();
        String path=i.getExtras().getString("PATH");

        //GET THE PDF FILE
        File file=new File(path);

        if(file.canRead())
        {
            //LOAD IT
            pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                    Toast.makeText(PDF_Activity.this, String.valueOf(nbPages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).load();
        }
    }
}
```

AND HOW TO CONNECT THE CODE ABOVE WITH THIS CODE?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DocumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(DocumentActivity.this,getPDFs()));

            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<PDFDoc> getPDFs()

    {
        ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs=new ArrayList<>();
        //TARGET FOLDER
        File downloadsFolder= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        //may results crash
        File documentsFolder= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        PDFDoc pdfDoc,pdfDoc2;

        if(downloadsFolder.exists())
        {
            //GET ALL FILES IN DOWNLOAD FOLDER
            File[] files=downloadsFolder.listFiles();

                //LOOP THRU THOSE FILES GETTING NAME AND URI
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    File file = files[i];

                    if (file.getPath().endsWith("pdf")) {
                        pdfDoc = new PDFDoc();
                        pdfDoc.setName(file.getName());
                        pdfDoc.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        pdfDocs.add(pdfDoc);
                    }
                }
        }
        // may result crash
        if(documentsFolder.exists())
        {
            //GET ALL FILES IN DOWNLOAD FOLDER
            File[] files2=documentsFolder.listFiles();

            //LOOP THRU THOSE FILES GETTING NAME AND URI
            for(int i = 0; i < files2.length; i++) {
                File file = files2[i];

                if (file.getPath().endsWith("pdf")) {
                    pdfDoc2 = new PDFDoc();
                    pdfDoc2.setName(file.getName());
                    pdfDoc2.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    pdfDocs.add(pdfDoc2);
                }
            }
        }
        return pdfDocs;
    }
}
```

Thanks For the HELP! Im Rush T.T

Comment: share your code and the build file code

Comment: don't paste your code as screenshots. You should first read [How to ask on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: first thing Use ScrollView instead of Scrollbar. show your log where the app is crashing

Comment: This is my First time to Ask question here Im sorry

Answer (score 0):

At Github ***"AndroidPdfViewerV1/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer/ScrollBar.java"***

solved this error